# Migration from ms sql to postgres nonascii characters error python

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, psycopg2, pyodbc

I need to create a python script to migrate data from Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSql. The problem occurs with non ascii characters. In Microsoft SQL Server I have a table named table1 with a column of type nvarchar which store a character

```
â
```

I am using pyodbc to retrieve the character. My connection string is

```
"ms_sql":{
    "DRIVER":"{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}",
    "SERVER":"(localdb)\\v11.0",
    "DATABASE":"sheshant_database",
    "Trusted_Connection":"yes",
    "charset":"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
```

The collation in ms sql is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. 
When I retrieve data in Python, it gives

```
u'\xe2'
```

Then I connect to postgres via psycopg2 and this is my connection string parameter

```
    "postgres":{
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "user":"postgres",
    "password":"regards",
    "database":"cmots",
    "port":"5432"
```

In PostgreSQL, the client and server encoding is 'latin1' and 'utf8' respectively. I used the command in psycopg2

```
'insert into table1 values ('+ a +');' // here a is a unicode and a = u'\xe2'
```

. But the data stored in PostgreSQL is

```
Γ
```

Where it went wrong?

Comment: If `pyodbc.version` does not return '4.0.6' then update pyodbc to the latest version. There have been several recent changes that could affect your results.

Comment: Also, try `cursor.execute('insert into table1 values (%s)', (a, ))`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows encoding and replace it:

```
cursor.execute ('insert into table1 values (%s)', a.decode('latin'));
```